# How to have one component on the left and one on the right by FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

In a part of my software I have a layout on bottom that holds couple of `JButton`s and a `JLabel`. I want to keep buttons one the right side of the panel, and label on the left side. I could manage to put buttons on the right, but do not know how to keep the `JLabel` on the left side.

Here is the code:

```
bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        
ftpBack = new JButton("Back");
ftpNext = new JButton("Next");
label = new JLabel("Text);

bottomPanel.add(label);
bottomPanel.add(ftpBack);
bottomPanel.add(ftpNext);

mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Any idea how to make it ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this with a `FlowLayout`.

You can use a horizontal `BoxLayout`:

```
Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
box.add(label);
box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
box.add(backButton);
box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
box.add(nextButton);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

Or another approach is to nest layout managers:

```
JPanel main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
main.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(back);
buttonPanel.add(next);
main.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```